# Conditionals: Replacing a value with a glyphicon

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, conditional-statements, glyphicons

I am trying to make it so if in my table a status is 'R' then it will replace that 'R' with the glyphicon, `glyphicon glyphicon-alert`.

I've thought of different ways of doing it such as making it a true or false condition because having 'G' appear is not necessary (if you could assist with making it if it is 'G' display ' ' that would be of use too)  but I haven't made much headway with that.

Can someone assist in this?

This is a plnkr of the code in question.

http://plnkr.co/edit/CTRlMFnw4bxXy8wYHTSP?p=preview

```
<tbody>
         <tr class="tt" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click for more information on {{x.c}}." ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" ng-repeat-    start="x in projects | filter:query | filter:myFilter | orderBy:orderProperty">
            <td class="shrink"><b>{{x.a}}</b></td>
            <td class="shrink">{{x.b}}</td>
            <td class="shrink"><u>{{x.c}}</u></td>
            <td class="shrink">{{x.d}}</td>
            <td class="shrink">{{x.e}}</td>
            <td class="shrink">{{x.f}}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr collapse="isCollapsed" ng-repeat-end="">
          <td colspan="6">
              <h3>Test</h3>
              <p>Test</p>
          </td>
        </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would fix it like this

```
<tr class="tt" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Click for more information on {{x.c}}." ng-click="isCollapsed = !isCollapsed" ng-repeat-start="x in projects | filter:query | filter:myFilter | orderBy:orderProperty">
   <td ng-class="{'glyphicon glyphicon-alert': x.a == 'R'}"><b ng-if="x.a != 'R'">{{x.a}}</b></td>
   <td class="shrink">{{x.b}}</td>
   <td class="shrink"><u>{{x.c}}</u></td>
   <td class="shrink">{{x.d}}</td>
   <td class="shrink">{{x.e}}</td>
   <td class="shrink">{{x.f}}</td>
</tr>
```